# Minimize dialog loading time in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I have a dialog box which consist two controls
a) combo box and 
b) Graph control.

When dialog is initialized the combo box contain 10 items.

Let's say for each item change I have to read large data point and plot them into a graph control. This whole activity per item change takes around 10 seconds.

There are two cases:

1. When I double click the dialog box the selection change of combo box will also fired which eventually reads the large data while loading a dialog and plot it into graph control. Due to which dialog takes lot of time to come up.
2. Further more when I do the selection change in combo box (when dialog is launched) it will read the data again. However I will do this activity on a seprate thread when dialog is already launched.

But my question is how can I minimize dialog loading time in **point 1** ? I need to minimize the dialog loading time.

Please help!!1

Comment: Can I ask what is the graph in your question, _"...plot it into graph..."_?

Comment: you can ignore the graph

Comment: Why I ask is that it is related with [UI Virtualization](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=338) and [Data virtualization](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344)

Comment: A bit far from what you expect, but you could pre-load the data in a separate thread and cache it for when you need to load the dialog, you don't have to do your costly call.

Comment: Thanks for the response. User may click the dialog any time then when do I load the data ?  Also the data may change based on the item selected in the combo box (user may save the current settings in the dialog). Is there any other way around ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit of hard time understanding what exactly is going on in point 1 - is the dialog closed, your press a button in your main window that opens the dialog, now opening the dialog takes a long time? Or is the dialog already open, you double click in it, and now it's slow (this doesn't make sense, because this should be point 2...)?

Anyway, if I'm understanding correctly and your main problem is, that upon opening your dialog you also load the graph, which causes the dialog to show up 10 seconds later, then this is what you need to do:

In the Dialog window `Loaded()` event handler populate your combobox and set its **selected index** (to whatever is apropriate, eg. 0). In the combobox `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler **create a background thread** that gets the graph data, and once it is done, update your Dialog window (eg. `this.Dispatcher.Invoke(...)`).

Although I don't understand how come you haven't done this already by implementing point 2...